# What does it mean the "starting address" of an executing thread?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, 64-bit

Would this mean what is the starting address of the first instruction to be executed or the address of the entry point of the thread that is currently executing or am I totally misunderstanding the answer ?

Comment: It is the address of the 1st instruction of the function being used as the thread procedure (entry point). "*the starting address of the first instruction to be executed ... the address of the entry point of the thread*" - they are the same thing.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you. If you can state the same in an answer I will accept.

Comment: this mean address of function passed to `CreateThread` (and related) - [`ThreadProc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms686736(v=vs.85)) or to native api for create thread. exist 2 different starting address - native and (not always exist) win32. for threads created by win32 api  native address always the same - `RtlUserThreadStart` , win32 start address - this is `ThreadProc`. this far from *first instruction to be executed*

Answer (score 0):

Threads share the same instructions so the "starting address" of the thread would be whatever the first instruction was that the thread executed and not, for example, any instructions that were used to start the thread in the parent.

Someone can correct me if I'm wrong but while threads can share the same data, they don't know who started them. As far as they are concerned they are their own process.